# Sudo command error in Mac OS X “no valid sudoers sources found, quitting”

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, sudo

How do I fix this response?

```
MacPro:~mymac$ sudo -i

sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

The sudoers file looks ok as far as I can tell.

Comment: Is the /etc/sudoers file exist?

Comment: Problem solved by re-installing El Capitan.